# rails_admin affecting view ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Where do I define how ‘belongs_to’ records are listed in rails_admin dashboard? I want my 'belongs_to' record to be listed by id. Because that’s what is determining how my records are displayed in view despite using .order(:id 'ASC') in controller.  Here are snap shots:

For example, when I load my records into the database and look in the database and the rails_admin dashboard, this is how same records are listed, i.e. in order of :id in the database but randomly in the rails_admin dashboard:
order in db and dashboard
[image: order in db and dashboard]

But when I look how they are displayed in view, even when I do entities.order(:id) in my code, they are displayed according to how they are listed in the rails_admin dashboard. Help will be appreciated.
 order in view
[image: order in view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model, you would want to define the ordering on the `has_many` relationship.

`has_many :children, -> { order(:id) }`